# EntityFramework - Updating many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a many-to-many relationship. I have two models, diary and tags. The model diary contains a list of tags and tags contains a list of diaries. But whenever I try to add another tag to an existing list or change an existing one I get thrown an exception:

**The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current context.**

Does my way of updating even work on collections? Or is there another approach I should be looking at?

Diary Model

```
public class Diary
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDiary { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string NameDiary { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public bool Locked { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Entry Model

```
public class Entry
{
    [Key]
    public int IdEntry { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string EntryText { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Diary_IdDiary")]
    public Diary Diary { get; set; }

    public int Diary_IdDiary { get; set; }
    public string EntryName { get; set; }
}
```

Tag Model

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Diary> Diaries { get; set; }
}
```

Update Method

```
    public void UpdateDiary(Diary updatedDiary)
    {
        var searchResult = SearchDiary(updatedDiary);
        if (searchResult != null)
        {
            updatedDiary.IdDiary = searchResult.IdDiary;
            _context.Entry(searchResult).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedDiary);
            _context.Entry(searchResult.Tags).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedDiary.Tags);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

SearchDiary Method

```
    public Diary SearchDiary(Diary searchDiary)
    {
        var queryResult =
            _context.Diaries.Include(d => d.Entries).Include(d => d.Tags)
                .Where(d => (d.NameDiary == searchDiary.NameDiary && d.CreationDate == searchDiary.CreationDate) || d.IdDiary == searchDiary.IdDiary);
        return queryResult.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Instead of `public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }` go with `public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }`. Do the same for `Entries`.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak Thank you, updated the models to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

**DiaryModel**

```
public class Diary
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDiary { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string NameDiary { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public bool Locked { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**EntryModel**

```
public class Entry
{
    [Key]
    public int IdEntry { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string EntryText { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Diary_IdDiary")]
    public virtual Diary Diary { get; set; }

    public int Diary_IdDiary { get; set; }
    public string EntryName { get; set; }
}
```

**For Search**

```
public Diary SearchDiary(int DiaryId)
{
    return _context.Diaries
        .Include(p => p.Entries)
        .Include(p => p.Tags)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.IdDiary == DiaryId);
}
```

**For Update**

```
public void UpdateDiary(Diary Diary)
{
    _context.Update(Diary);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You should pass the modified `Diary` object to the update functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is updating the diary itself, but I'm afraid it's not updating the tags. If I type in a tag it's able to create the tag but it doesn't create the relation between the diary and the tag.